# Dashes in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

**WordPress 5.0.3**

I'm reading my first book on WordPress.

I'm just creating a child theme of an existing Twenty Seventeen theme.

In the book it is said for me to create functions.php and paste this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpquickstart_enqueue_styles' ); 
function wpquickstart_enqueue_styles() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-seventeen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpquickstart-style',    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
        array('twenty-seventeen-style')    ); 
}
```

Well, being framed in  it works, which is strange to me.
What bothers me is the first dash in twenty-seventeen-style.

I mean this also works (attention to twentyseventeen-style, to dashes in it):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpquickstart_enqueue_styles' ); 
function wpquickstart_enqueue_styles() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpquickstart-style',    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
        array('twentyseventeen-style')    ); 
}
?>
```

Could you tell me whether dashes are ignored? Where can I read some documentaion on this moment?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing a second argument to [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/), it's defining the `ha dle` as that `source`. If you registered a handle and source with `wp_register_style()` previously, then you wouldn't need to pass a source argument to `wp_enqueue_style()` as long as you called the handle identically.

Otherwise, since you're defining the handle and the source at the same time, it's effectively arbitrary. However if you ever need to dequeue, modify, add inline styles to, etc, your enqueued style - you'll so it by using the handle you've passed here (with or without the dashes).

**Edit**: To simplify a little bit:

When you write:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

You, Michael, are adding a stylesheet named `twentyseventeen-style` that's located at `/template/style.css`.

You can name it whatever you want, and it will still load. For instance, this will work as well:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'blahblah-michaels-2k17-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
```

That first argument is the name YOU are giving the stylesheet located at the second argument's location.

Comment: To tell the truth, I can't  understand anything of what you said. I have mentioned, that I'm just a beginner. This the first functions.php in my life. Could you write it a bit simpler? What troubles me is wp_enqueue_style( 'twenty-seventeen-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );  I can see that this string gets a templage directory of the mentioned theme. Why can it mention with or without dashes?

Comment: I've clarified it a little bit. You may want to read through the source documentation for `wp_enqueue_style()` as well: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/